# Core-Plot: Removing line that connects points in Scatterplot?

Tags: xcode, core-plot

I would like to simply show scatterplot points. Actually, two sets of scatterplot points with different colors.

However, it seems that the default condition of a scatterplot is to connect the dots. I've tried to set the CPTMutableLineStyle properties to nil, but the line still shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide lines in Core Plot by setting the corresponding line style to `nil`.

```
scatterPlot.dataLineStyle = nil;
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. I guess the only thing that I must have done differently was to put the line in a different place in the sequence of instructions.